Selenium runs locally but not in github Actions

I am running this selenium tests in locally and this works fine and find all XPaths fines,but if I try to run this code in GitHubActions the code gives an error saying it did not find the XPath for 'name'. Someone can help?

Code:
 [TestFixture]
    public class CETestsActionDev
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        private readonly string environment = "dev";

        private static int _randomNumber;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            //They re commented because if not, code in gbActions doesnt find even "userName"
            //ChromeOptions options = new();
            //options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            //options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            //options.AddArgument("--headless");

            driver = new ChromeDriver();    
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        }
   [Test]
   public void SuccessCloudExpertProfile()
   {
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https:comapnyExemplo.com");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    string emailDev = "davi262016+100@gmail.com";

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='userName']")).SendKeys(emailDev);
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='password']")).SendKeys("testCloud2Gether");

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='buttonForm']")).Click();

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

     AddPublicNameAndAboutField(driver);
   //First xpath from this method is "name"
 AddLanguages(driver);
 RemoveLanguages(driver);
 CorrectAdress(driver);
 }


GitHub Actions Yaml:
Test_Project_Path: C2GSeleniumTeste.csproj
steps:

name: Checkout
uses: actions/checkout@v4
with:
fetch-depth: 0

name: Install .NET Core
uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
with:
dotnet-version: 8.0.x

name: Install Chrome
uses: browser-actions/setup-chrome@v1
with:
chrome-version: 'stable'

name: Restore dependencies
run: dotnet restore ${{ env.Test_Project_Path }}

name: Run tests
run: dotnet test ${{ env.Test_Project_Path }} --configuration Release --logger trx --results-directory .

name: Upload test results
if: failure()
uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
with:
name: test-results
path: '*.trx'
if-no-files-found: warn


I want to run selenium code in GithubActions but im not having success

When the tests were running in GitHub Actions, the reCAPTCHA was activated.
